# How to update Sales cloud Record for PersonAccount from CloudPage?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, person-accounts, subscriber-key

I have PersonAccounts enabled in the Sales cloud Org. We are using Subscriber Key as PersonContactId in Marketing cloud. We have a cloud page from which we need to update PersonAccount in Salescloud and are able to get the Subscriber Key in a ampscript variable, but if we use the PersonContactId to update the Sales cloud record from Cloud Page, it gives an error.

How can we update a Account/PersonAccount from CloudPage where we have the PersonContactId as the Subscriber Key?

Comment: Please can you share the code that you've tried which returns an error?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to update on the Account object. I assume you're using the `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` function.

Note that in the newer APIs, the Contact is completely read-only if it is attached to an account (as in, a Person Account). Instead, use the same field on the account, and update that instead.

```
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Account', @PersonContactId, 'PersonEmail', 'info@salesforce.com')
```

Comment: I'm using the same ampscript but nothing is happing on the SF end. I have checked the permissions on SF end as well, they are fine there.